# The hazelcast query get slow when I query huge data, How improve?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I use hazelcast version is 4.0.3. The Map in hazelcast size is 120000.
I query this Map use PagingPredicate, every time I query 10000 data. So I query 12 times. I find first query cost 1 second about, and sencond time query cost 5 second. The last query cost 20 second. this is slower every query. Why? How can I do to improve the query performance?

Comment: Did you check your heap usage and garbage collection pattern?

Comment: My Heap usage is not 50%，and garbage collection pattern is g1. but I query 10000 data from 1340000 datas map cost 30 second，and hazelcast show it is a slow operations

Comment: How many servers do you have in the cluster and how much memory do 1340000 entries occupy?

Comment: I have 3 servers in the cluster，every server have 32G memory

Comment: Its still not clear how much space does your entire data set needs for storage on the cluster. Nevertheless, I suggest that you change the in-memory-format setting to OBJECT. If the problem persists, run a profiler on the cluster to identify bottlenecks.